# React Native Bundle output path v0.14.2

Tags: ios, react-native

I am running the following command to create a bundle file:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file=index.ios.js --platform=ios --bundle-output=./ios/main.jsbundle
```

I am uncommenting the jsCodeLocation for Option 2 and commented out Option 1. When I attempt to run my app in XCode (with simulator) I get an error message (Chrome Debug)

```
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'file:///Users/chris7519/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../Application/.../myapp.app/main.jsbundle' failed to load.
```

I'm not well versed in iOS development, but what am I missing? Also, I am using the new asset system to reference my images. Not sure if I need to use the --assets-dest option but this is a brand new project (React Native v0.14.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getting that error because your building against the simulator in Xcode.

Switch to your device and this goes away.

If you didn't intent to run against the bundle re-comment this in AppDelegate.m

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

and turn your local dev server back on:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

Comment: But is it possible to debug an app in Chrome while building against a bundle?

Answer (score 2):

There is another legitimate reason why you can get the error.

In addition to the accepted answer above, if you have chrome debugging turned on, then you can/will also get that error.